# @SetViewInfo with Sorted Columns

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Can someone advise whether @SetViewInfo can be used with click to sort columnns.

When a view is filtered using @SetViewInfo it removes the column sorting options, thus removing the functionality of the view. Even when resetting to all records the column sorting option is not available, however I have overcome this by opening a second view then opening the original view, messy but it works. I am using View Action Buttons. (Not sure how to store the value in a Check Box Action).

Filtering

```
  @SetViewInfo([SetViewFilter]; "userinitials"; "$80"; 1)
```

Resetting.

```
 @SetViewInfo([SetViewFilter];"";"$80";1);
 @SetTargetFrame("frame");
 @Command([OpenView]; "DummyView"); //Needed to get the click to sort back
 @Command([OpenView]; "OriginalView")
```

Also if the view is already sorted on another column, ie not in a categorised state no records are found. I don't want to have to remove the sorting options on my views. The help implies you don't need to have the view categorised. But I cannot get it to work if I don't, ie if I use 0 on an uncategorised view nothing happens.

From Help

*isCategory - Number. Boolean value. Required in a Standard Outline view; not for use in Calendar views. 1 indicates that the column in the columnName value is a category. 0 indicates that it is not.*

Is the @SetViewInfo limited as I have found or am I missing something?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, @SetViewInfo has limitations. As far as I know, you cannot keep the sorting  when you use SetViewFilter. I also believe you need to have the view categorized, at least in older versions of Notes this was the case, if I remember correctly.
Limitations like this is why I personally don't use @SetViewInfo very often (if at all), I try to use other ways to display filtered documents.
One way I have handled it in the past is to use a special form with a rich text field, and then I build a list of filtered documents (e.g. through a search) and render the list of documents in the rich text item.
I use this technique to do that: http://blog.texasswede.com/dynamic-tables-in-classic-notes/

Comment: Thanks Karl-Henry, I slowly realised I was wasting my time, one day maybe. It isn't applicable in this instance as I need to filter hundreds of documents, but wow, I will definitely be making use of your dynamic table, so slick.

Comment: @MarkMaden thank you, I hope you can use it some time, I found it very useful in the past.  
If you create Domino web applications, you have more options to filter a view. One nice way to do it is to expose the Notes view as a JSON feed, and then use for example DataTables.js to display a table that the user can sort an filter on any way they like. 
Here is a presentation from 2016 describing one way to do that, using the plugin bootstrap-tables: https://www.slideshare.net/TexasSwede/break-out-of-the-box-part-2

Comment: Thanks again Karl-Henry, my developments are either Notes or XPages, I have done little with Domino web applications so that is a good start for me.